# Token undeclared error in a macro that does token pasting

Tags: c, macros

I'm not posting the exact code here, but I have tried to represent the problem fully. I have the following macro -

```
#define TKN_PST(P) (ABC_##P)
```

This macro is called in the definition of another macro, which itself is called from another macro as below -

```
#define CREATE_TOKEN(P) FURTHER_PROC(P)
#define FURTHER_PROC(X) foo(a, b, TKN_PST(X), ...)
```

foo() is a function that accepts a variable number of arguments.

I'm getting an error when I call `CREATE_TOKEN(P)`. The compiler tells me that `ABC_` is undeclared.

This problem only occurs when I call `CREATE_TOKEN(P)`, and doesn't occur for `CREATE_TOKEN(Q)`, `CREATE_TOKEN(R)`, etc. I suspect that this issue might be the result of P having a definition somewhere in the large code-base.

I tried introducing an extra level of indirection as below -

```
#define FURTHER_PROC(X) FURTHER_PROC2(X)
#define FURTHER_PROC2(X) foo(a, b, TKN_PST(X), ...)
```

Then `CREATE_TOKEN(Q)`, `CREATE_TOKEN(R)`, etc started failing with the error "')' expected before ...".

What might be the reason for this issue?

Comment: As you know, `ABC_ is undeclared` means your preprocessor expanded the "P" in  "TKN_PST(P)" to "".   Since "Q" and "R" seem to work ... I agree with  your guess that "P" is itself a macro, defined "somewhere else".  SUGGESTION: Compile with `-E` (or equivalent for your compiler) to debug the macro expansion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did find a definition elsewhere that is included in the file where these macros are defined.
That definition is just a #define with no replacement text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to paulsm4 for pointing me in the right direction with his comment above.

I was able to find a definition (#define) for "P" in an included file, which has no replacement text.
I hadn't considered this possibility.